# Jmeter Graph Listener for SampleResult.subResult

Tags: graph, jmeter, listeners

I am looking for a jmeter graph listener that will output the subresults of a SamplerRequest object. I haven't found one yet and I'm very keen on getting it.

Comment: What it SamplerRequest object? Never heard of... Could you provide a link?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say SampleResult not 'SamplerRequest'.

Comment: One more question - what is "output"? View Results Tree component of Jmeter shows subresults well...

Comment: I want to graph the subresults. I can see the output nicely in the ViewResults Tree but I'm not able to graph the subresults. The Summary, aggreagate and other listeners only seem to display the statisitics for the root element not the suresults. FYI..I'm new to jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know.

Unfortunately, it appears that there are no JMeter graph listeners that will graph the results of sub results attached to a SampleResult. Having just been faced with the same problem, I chose to write my own.

Steps:

1. Compile the below class as a jar.
2. Place the jar in jMeter's lib/ext folder.
3. Open your test plan, navigate through the menu's to add a Listener as normal, selecting "SubResult Distributed Response Graph"
4. Run your test plan.

Classes:

The below class will provide a Response Time Distribution graph, that will only graph Sub Results.

```
public class SubResultDistributedResponseTimeListener extends DistributionGraphVisualizer {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass();

@Override
public void add(final SampleResult res) {
    final List<SampleResult> subResults = Arrays.asList(res.getSubResults());
    final SubResultDistributedResponseTimeListener inst = this;

    JMeterUtils.runSafe(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (SampleResult r : subResults) {
                long time = r.getEndTime() - r.getStartTime();
                LOG.info("Adding result; start: " + r.getStartTime() + " end: " + r.getEndTime() + " duration: " + time);
                SamplingStatCalculator model = inst.getCustomModel();
                if (model != null) {
                    model.addSample(r);
                    inst.updateGui(model.getCurrentSample());
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

// we need this because DistributionGraphVisualizer has a private field 'model' which
// deals with updating the screen. Watch out for SecurityManager problems with 
// accessing private fields.
public SamplingStatCalculator getCustomModel() {
    try {
        Field f = DistributionGraphVisualizer.class.getDeclaredField("model");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        return (SamplingStatCalculator) f.get(this);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "SubResult Distributed Response Graph";
}

@Override
public String getStaticLabel() {
    return this.getName();
}

@Override
public String getLabelResource() { // add this Listeners name to the right click context menu.
    return this.getName();
}
```

NB, the horrendously ugly catch block was because I had to compile in Java 1.5.

I'll leave it to the reader to extend different graph listeners should they wish.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I know is [Hits Per Second](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/HitsPerSecond) graph, it plots results and subresults, but only from Transaction Controllers, not embedded resources. You may ask authors to implement a new graph...