# Creating a JMeter Java sampler and getting multiple response times

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm creating a JMeter test for EJB method calls extending AbstractJavaSamplerClient class. I have several method calls which has to be done in order and I want to get response times each of them. Is it somehow possible to get JMeter to report several response times from one test class? I've not found a way to do this.

**EDIT1:**
So I would like to get separate response times from call1 and call2.

```
public class JavaRequestSamplerDemo extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

  @Override
  public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext ctx) {
    SampleResult sampleResult = new SampleResult();
    sampleResult.sampleStart();
    class.call1();
    class.call2();
    sampleResult.sampleEnd();
    sampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
    sampleResult.setResponseCodeOK();
    sampleResult.setResponseMessageOK();
    return sampleResult;
  }  
}
```

Comment: See `SampleResult.addSubResult();` - https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html. Post your classes code and I'll post an appropriate answer for you.

Answer (score 3):

As promised in the comment, try this:

```
public class JavaRequestSamplerDemo extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

@Override
public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext ctx) {
    SampleResult mainResult = new SampleResult();
    mainResult.sampleStart();

    SampleResult child = new SampleResult();
    child.sampleStart();
    class.call1();
    child.sampleEnd();
    // set the other properties of the 'child' SampleResult, such as successful etc here.

    mainResult.addSubResult(child);

    child = new SampleResult();
    child.sampleStart();
    class.call2();
    child.sampleEnd();
    // again, set the properties of this child appropriately (successful etc).

    mainResult.addSubResult(child);
    mainResult.setSuccessful(true);
    mainResult.setResponseCodeOK();
    mainResult.setResponseMessageOK();
    return mainResult;
    }  
}
```

NB, the downside is that none of the native JMeter Listeners support SubResults. I wrote a few and have posted an example in the answers to this question: [Jmeter Graph Listener for SampleResult.subResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272926/jmeter-graph-listener-for-sampleresult-subresult)

Comment: Thanks Dave! I already played with this a bit, it's really unfortunate that listeners are not supporting SubResults. Do you know if there is a listener available for Aggregate Graph somewhere? I would like to get data to that table where the statistics are.

Comment: I searched for all sorts of Listeners that support SubResults (there's a lot of requests, but nothing implemented that I could see). Using the answer I posted on the linked question, if you extend `org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.StatGraphVisualizer` (found in ApacheJMeter_components-2.9.jar) and implement the `add()` method properly, you should have a Listener that does what you want. Looking at the code, you'll want to add multiple rows in the model, one row per SubResult. Comment back if you run into problems. :-)

Comment: Thanks again Dave! Let's see if I have time and skills to try that.  I'll definitely get back to you if I get into problems :)

Comment: There is probably not even possibility save the subresults to the disk? At least Simple Data Writer doesn't seem to support that. Only View Results Tree seems to understand subresults...

Comment: Nope, I couldn't see anything that supported SubResults other than View Results. That's why I reverted to writing my own. You shouldn't have any problems writing a Listener that will output to disk (I'd advise against writing to disk in the Sampler). Fun isn't it? ;-)

Comment: I'm still catching up the fun part :)